# Is there a way to reset the rest of the checkbox item when clicking 'None of the above option' in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I've been struggling with reactive forms with checkboxes .

1. If none of the items is selected , submit button should be disabled . This is done
2. There's an option called "None of the above" . Selecting this should unselect all the selected items(if any) in the checkboxes
3. Selecting back any item but 'None of the above' should unselect the 'None of the above'

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <label formArrayName="orders" *ngFor="let order of form.controls.orders.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" (click)="onChange(orderData)">
    {{ordersData[i].name}}
  </label>
  <br>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">submit</button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
  onChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

You can find complete code related to this on **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcfzhi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi try this stackblitz first https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqggqr

1. You have to remove None of the above option from your array and put
   it outside of `*ngFor`
2. Use a variable for None of the above to make change when user change the check box `<input type="checkbox" [checked]="uncheck" (change)="unCheckAll()" />`
3. In your `.ts` In `unCheckAll()` reset your form and all checkbox will
   be changed.
4. In `onChange()` just set `uncheck` variable to `false`.

Everything is implemented in above stackblitz

Comment: Hey @AliWahab Thanks . But clicking on "None of the above" should disable the submit Button .

Comment: Hi @AnushaKrishnamurthy, I have update the stackblitz. Please check and review. 
There was a little issue in your code. You used `(click)` on input type check box. `change` event should be used when working with checkbox and select. 
I have modified the code please see the `onChange()` and `unCheckAll()` methods. Currently it is just enabling the button. Form is still invalid beacuse nothing is checked. If you want  `nocheckbox` value in your form. We have to come up with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do simple change to `onChange(event)` method. You can do this easily using **`setValue`** and **`patchValue`** in Angular **`FormArray`**.

Pass **`formControlName`** to the `onChange` method as an `argument`. In your case it is `index`. Use **`setValue`** and **`patchValue`** to change values to the `elements` in the **`FormArray`**.

**HTML**

```
...
<input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" (click)="onChange(i)">
...
```

**TS**

```
  onChange(index) {
    if (index === 3)
      this.form.controls.orders.setValue([false, false, false, true]);
    else
      this.form.controls.orders.get('3').patchValue(false);
  }
```

**[StackBlitz Demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-izndgn?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: 1. If none of the items is selected , submit button should be disabled. It's not working with your code

Answer (score 0):

update your onChange function to take object of order data

```
onChange(event: any) {
const indexOfNone = this.ordersData.findIndex(function(item, i) {
  return item.name.toUpperCase() === "NONE OF THE ABOVE";
});

if (event.name.toUpperCase() == "NONE OF THE ABOVE") {
  this.arrays.controls.forEach(e => {
    e.setValue(false);
  });
  this.form.controls.orders.get(indexOfNone.toString()).patchValue(true);
} else
  this.form.controls.orders.get(indexOfNone.toString()).patchValue(false);
```

}

and also your html like so

```
 <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" (click)="onChange(ordersData[i])" name="orders"  [value]="ordersData[i].name"  >
{{ordersData[i].name}}
```

feel free to take out the loop 
`const indexOfNone = this.ordersData.findIndex(function(item, i) {
      return item.name.toUpperCase() === "NONE OF THE ABOVE";
    });` 
to somewhere global perhaps if the value will not change after init time, that should minimize the performance cost as it doesn't need to loop everytime a checkbox value is changed.